# Make Mac Console Application Terminal invisible

Tags: macos, bash, swift2, command-line-tool

I am new to Mac OS X apps programming, i have created a Command line tool in xcode using swift 2.

That Command tool actually opens one other installed app (basically just few bash commands), but problem is, when i run "exec - product of script" by navigating to build, it makes a white terminal window which remains open but do opens external app, even if i close my external app, that terminal window remained open.

So i don't want that terminal window to even show. So how to make terminal/product of script invisible.

I searched a lot, but maybe not searching correctly, i tried searching " Console app on Mac", found less results than expected.

Please help

Thanks,
Mac 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Command line programs require a *standard in* and *standard out* so when you invoke them via *Finder* the system provides a terminal session for them to run in.

You'll need to repackage your code as an *Agent* or something.

Comment: As an agent or something ?? Can u send me few links to get started. Thanks

Comment: I think you want something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).

Comment: Thanks alot, also i was wondering, if that terminal can exit itself after executing that would also do the job, i am lookine into the link you provided, but if exiting terminal is possible, than it could save us recoding all stuff. Thanks a lot

Comment: I would have expected the terminal to terminate when the command line program exits.  Does it not do that?

Comment: No it doesn't, after executing it shows process completed and stucks, i tried putting exit(0) in swift script too. Should i post a screenshot ?

Comment: What about if you create a script to call your program: `#!/bin/sh exec ./program` (that's two lines), and click on that instead?

Comment: How will we compile and run this script ?? I have one question: this script will run the swift product right ?

Comment: You use a text editor then set its execute-bit from the command line using `chmod 0755 myscript.sh`.  Yes it will a Swift-implemented command line utility.